# chrome broadcast message to content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to broadcast a chrome message to all content scripts of a chrome extension?

chrome.runtime.sendMessage() takes a tabId as an input. However if there are multiple tabs running with the content script, how could one broadcast to all the tabs?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you meant `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` having the tab ID argument.

There are 2 `sendMessage` functions in Chrome API:

- [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) will broadcast to all pages running in `chrome-extension://your-extension-id/` origin.

That would be the background page, the popup (if open), the options page (if open) and any tabs to extension pages you opened yourself.

- [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) will broadcast to all content scripts of your extension running in the tab provided (soon with a possiblity to filter by frame), or the current active tab if the ID is not provided.

There is, unfortunately, no function to broadcast to all content scripts. So, you have two possible approaches:

### 1 - Carpet bombing

Just broadcast to all tabs one by one!

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message);
  });
});
```

If you want to narrow it down by match pattern, you can:

```
// Even accepts arrays of patterns!
chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://*.example.com/*"}, function(tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message);
  });
});
```

### 2 - Tab/connection tracking

You can be more proactive and track the tabs that are ready to receive your messages. It can be tedious, however, to maintain that list.

In practice, you can instead make your content scripts open port connections to your background page, and then use the list of open ports to send a command to them. The downside being that you can't use an event page for this, as it needs to keep connections open.

Comment: Method 1 is what I've used but it comes with pesky warning errors (e.g. "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.") when you broadcast to tabs which _do not_ have your content-script loaded (ie their URLs weren't matched).